# What databases which allow debug stored procedure?

Tags: database, stored-procedures

While going through some online references on how to debug MySQL stored procedures, found that MySQL does not provide facilities for debugging stored procedures.

Can anyone educate me what are other databases which allows to debug stored procedures?

Comment: SQL Server for instance

Comment: For MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-visual-studio-debugger.html